# Getting features attributes on feature selection in QGIS python?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I want to know how to get features from a layer on click event.. using python(m trying to create a plugin).. the below code always show 0 output

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
print len(selection)
for feature in selection:
    print feature['NAME']
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me

layer = iface.activeLayer()

h = layer.selectedFeatures()

for f in h:
    print f['ID']